# Unable to open winecfg

Tags: wine, winetricks

I am trying to launch `$ winecfg` but `0024:err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Importing dlls for L"C:\\windows\\syswow64\\start.exe" failed, status c0000135` shows up and it does not launch

Comment: Looks like you're trying to run a Windows `.exe`` (executable) on Linux.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after my installation following the steps from this website: [WineHQ On Ubuntu 22.04 LTS](https://linuxhint.com/install-winehq-on-ubuntu-22-04/) and others users had the same problem as in [this website](https://www.reddit.com/r/wine_gaming/comments/q9szsz/i_cannot_open_either_exe_files_or_winecfg_help/), it seems that no one could solve this problem.

So I had to remove all `wine`, including `wine32`, `wine64`, `winehq`, etc. not only typing the command `sudo apt-get remove` but also `sudo apt-get autoremove` to clean all in the hard disk. And then, I followed the steps from [this website](https://linuxhint.com/install-use-wine-linux/) without `winehq`, after that I could open `winecfg` and also install or run any Windows app without any problem similar.

From my point of view, the problem is this: `winehq-stable`, `winehq-devel`, `winehq-staging`; I think it's about all kind of `winehq`, I don't know why but I don't recommend to install them to avoid any serious problem that makes impossible to solve it.

Comment: Unless you have a specific requirement for a specific version of wine, it's easiest to just install the one from the Ubuntu repos.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I remember when I was researching so much, I read that this problem caused by winehq of the version 6 and above, since 2021. I don't remember well.